# How to start application on mobile device from desktop application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-ce, opennetcf

In my szenario i copy an application to a mobile device (Windows CE) from a desktop application (VB.NET, Win7). It is a small setup routine.

Is it possible to start the setup application on the mobile device from within the dektop application after copying the files to the mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to use the [CeCreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922104.aspx) function from RAPI. It has its own limitations for example: [Wait for CECreateProcess complete](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsmobiledev/thread/945cbabc-9036-4a6a-a5e1-f9904e26ec0d)